# How can I screen-scrape output from telnet in Perl?

Tags: perl, telnet, curses

I can setup a telnet connection in Perl no problems, and have just discovered Curses, and am wondering if I can use the two together to scrape the output from the telnet session.

I can view on a row, column basis the contents of STDOUT using the simple script below:

```
use Curses;
my $win = new Curses;
$win->addstr(10, 10, 'foo');
$win->refresh;
my $thischar=$win->inch(10,10);
print "Char $thischar\n";
```

And using the below I can open a telnet connection and send \ receive commands with no problem:

```
use net::telnet;
my $telnet = new Net::Telnet (Timeout => 9999,);
$telnet->open($ipaddress) or die "telnet open failed\n";
$telnet->login($user,$pass);
my $output = $telnet->cmd("command string");
```

... But what I would really like to do is get the telnet response (which will include terminal control characters) and then search on a row \ column basis using curses. Does anyone know of a way I can connect the two together? It seems to me that curses can only operate on STDOUT

Comment: What is the nature of this "scrape"?  Since you originally thought you could use curses, it seems you are looking for means to respond in real-time to the data on your screen.  Are your program's future actions in the telnet session determined by past responses?  Or do you just want to examine/analyze the log of a session after having ended the session?  Is the data of interest really row/column dependent?  Is this a real application or a school exercise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are interacting purely with plain-text commands and responses, you can use [Expect](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Expect/) to script that, otherwise, you can use [Term::VT102](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Term-VT102/), which lets you screen scrape (read specific parts of the screen,  send text, handle events on scrolling, cursor movement, screen content changes, and others) applications using VT102 escape sequences for screen control (e.g., an application using the curses library).

Answer (score 5):

Curses does the opposite.  It is a C library for optimising screen updates from a program writing to a terminal, originally designed to be used over a slow serial connection.  It has no ability to scrape a layout from a sequence of control characters.

A better bet would be a terminal emulator that has an API with the ability to do this type of screen scraping.  Off the top of my head I'm not sure if any Open-source terminal emulators do this, but there are certainly commercial ones available that can.

Answer (score 4):

You probably want something like [Expect](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Expect)

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Expect;

my $exp = Expect->spawn("telnet google.com 80");

$exp->expect(15, #timeout
        [
                qr/^Escape character.*$/,
                sub {
                        $exp->send("GET / HTTP/1.0\n\n");
                        exp_continue;
                }
        ]
);
```

Comment: Thanks Vinko.. The problem with Expect is that it can't interpolate the terminal control characters, so it tends to get confused by all the screen positioning that comes back as part of the telnet data

Comment: @Mike: expect has been used to play many different roguelike games - it shouldn't be getting confused by ncurses.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for [Term::VT102](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Term::VT102), which emulates a VT102 terminal (converting the terminal control characters back into a virtual screen state).  There's an example showing how to use it with [Net::Telnet](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net::Telnet) in [VT102/examples/telnet-usage.pl](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/AJWOOD/Term-VT102-0.91/VT102/examples/telnet-usage.pl) (the examples directory is inside the VT102 directory for some reason).

It's been about 7 years since I used this (the system I was automating switched to a web-based interface), but it used to work.

Comment: That's brilliant! Thanks very much for your help, massively appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use the **script** command for this.

From the Solaris man-page:

> #### DESCRIPTION
>
> The `script` utility makes a record of everything  printed
> on your  screen.  The record is written to *filename*. If no file name
> is given, the record is saved in the file  *typescript*...
>
> The script command forks and creates a
> sub-shell,  according to  the value of
> $SHELL, and records the text from this
> session. The script ends when the
> forked shell  exits  or  when
> Control-d is typed.

Answer (score 0):

I would vote also for the Expect answer.  I had to do something similar from a gui'ish application.  The trick (albeit tedious) to get around the control characters was to strip all the misc characters from the returned strings. It kind of depends on how messy the screen scrape ends up being.

Here is my function from that script as an example:

```
# Trim out the curses crap
sub trim {
    my @out = @_;
    for (@out) {
        s/\x1b7//g;
        s/\x1b8//g;
        s/\x1b//g;   # remove escapes
        s/\W\w\W//g;
        s/\[\d\d\;\d\dH//g;  # 
        s/\[\?25h//g;
        s/\[\?25l//g;
        s/\[\dm//g;
        s/qq//g;
        s/Recall//g;
        s/\357//g;
        s/[^0-9:a-zA-Z-\s,\"]/ /g;
        s/\s+/ /g;    # Extra spaces

    }
    return wantarray ? @out : $out[0];
}
```